# SELECT not returning anything using HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get the total percentage off and only return the matches >+ 80. However, this doesn't return any results:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE Available=1 AND Merchant='Amazon' HAVING (LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) / LowestNewPrice * 100 >= ?
```

Am I using `HAVING` correctly?

Comment: Your main problem is the your percentage formula is wrong. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate function used in SELECT statement.

`HAVING` is applied after the aggregation phase and must be used if you want to filter aggregate results.

Your query is wrong. 
What you can do is do the conditioning in where clause only.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE Available=1 
AND Merchant='Amazon' 
AND (LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) / LowestNewPrice * 100 >= ?
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't return anything. Doesn't this need a comparision? `"(LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) / LowestNewPrice * 100 >= ?`

Comment: What do you understand by '?'. You have to have some operand there. With which you want to compare.

Comment: Sorry, the `?` is a plceholder for a PHP PDO operation. In this case the `?` is == to 80

Comment: I think `?` is just a a param. He copied it from profiler may be.

Comment: Run the query with 80 as the value. You will get the desired results.

Comment: Just use 80 instead of ? and run your query you will get desired result if exists.

Answer (score 1):

As per I understand you wanna use `having` to filter whereas you may use just `where` condition.

About returning results, your query will produce syntax error. If you use as following and don't get any result then obviously it is because of conditions and your data. In that case if you provide data, you may get some help.

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE Available=1 
AND Merchant='Amazon' 
AND (LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) / LowestNewPrice * 100 >= ?
```

Comment: check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/703fb0/2 and explain me that why that sql statement work without group by

Comment: It will not work in sql server. Though he tagged mysql & sql.

Comment: I'm trying to say is your statement group by is must for having is incorrect

Comment: Agreed. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) / LowestNewPrice * 100 as percentage FROM products WHERE Available=1 AND Merchant='Amazon' HAVING  percentage  >= ?
```

Comment: Where is `percentage` coming from in this query?

Comment: it is there in the select columns as calculated column

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your percentage formula is wrong. Use

```
((LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) / LowestNewPrice) * 100
```

or

```
(LowestUsedPrice - LowestNewPrice) * 100 / LowestNewPrice
```

The way you are using will do something like

```
(20 - 8) / 15 * 100

12 / 1500 = 0.008
```

And you need

```
1200 / 15 = 80
```

Add this fix to the solution on other answers

Comment: I think `*` and `/` have the same precedence.